# Parallel transform of a vector by Lie derivative

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

I am new to differential geometry and I learn by myself. It seems that we need something extra called a connection to parallel transport a vector along a curve.

But, suppose we have a vector field $X $, the vector field induces some flow $\phi_t $ on the manifold, which in turn can be viewed as a diffeomorphism of the manifold. Therefore, we can **push forward** the vector! Can we consider this as a parallel transport of the initial vector?

If not, what is the drawback?

Comment: The infinitesimal generator of the push forward is the Lie derivative: $\mathcal L_X v = X \cdot \nabla v - v \cdot \nabla X$.  The infinitesimal generator of parallel transport is covariant derivative https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariant_derivative#Vector_fields.  So go through the axioms of a covariant derivative, and see if the Lie derivative satisfies them.

Comment: A question that should push you down the right path: Given a curve, what vector field $X$ do you push along?

Comment: @AnthonyCarapetis You mean a curve has too low a dimension. You need a vector field defined everywhere to push forward some vector.

Comment: Right. You could extend the tangent vector field to a neighbourhood of the curve (indeed this is how parallel transport is done using a connection!), but you'd need the pushforward to be independent of the chosen extension, which is not true.